# Error Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider]

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, c3p0

I have an error in Hibernate 4.1.2.FINAL, JBoss 7.1.1,and Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE,like this:

```
12:10:50,853 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) 
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'departamentoDao' defined in URL [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in URL [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Caused by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in URL 
    [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]: 
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL 
    [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]: 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

and :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nestwared exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: 
Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
>>Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service
>>Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
```

and my spring-hibernate configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>
   <bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="vehicDataSource">
<!-- p:lobHandler-ref="defaultLobHandler"-->
<property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <!-- Procedimientos -->
        <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.HabilitacionVehicular_Inscripcion</value>
    <!-- Main Properties -->
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.Transportista</value>
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.Ubigeo</value>
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.TransportistaNatural</value>
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.TransportistaJuridico</value>
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.Conductor</value>
    <!-- Transportista's Ubigeo -->
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.ubigeo.Departamento</value>
    <value>com.reglamb.projvehimerc.domain.ubigeo.Distrito</value>
    </list>
  </property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.default_schema=${hibernate.default_schema}
            hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_size=${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.min_size=${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.timeout=${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}
            hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}
            hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}
            <!--hibernate.c3p0.validate=${hibernate.c3p0.validate}-->
            <!--hibernate.cache.provider_class=${hibernate.cache.provider_class}-->
            hibernate.connection.provider_class=${hibernate.connection.provider_class}
            hibernate.show_sql=${hibernate.show_sql}
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=${hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings}
            <!-- Auto Generated Schemas and tables not good for production
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update-->
            <!--hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true-->
            <!--hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true-->
         </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
 <!-- Transaction Config -->
 <bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>   
 <!-- Hibernate Template -->
 <bean id="hibernateTemplate" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" 
p:sessionFactory-ref ="sessionFactory"/>

 <!-- Injectores Procedimiento -->
 <bean id="inscriptransportistaDao" 
class="com.reglamb.projvehimerc.dao.hibernate.HabilitacionVehicular_InscripcionDaoHibernate" > 
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref ="hibernateTemplate" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Injectores Ubigeo -->
 <bean id="ubigeoDao" 
class="com.reglamb.projvehimerc.dao.hibernate.UbigeoDaoHibernate" > 
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref ="hibernateTemplate" />
 </bean>
  <bean id="departamentoDao" 
class="com.reglamb.projvehimerc.dao.hibernate.ubigeo.DepartamentoDaoHibernate" > 
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref ="hibernateTemplate" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="distritoDao" 
class="com.reglamb.projvehimerc.dao.hibernate.ubigeo.DistritoDaoHibernate" > 
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref ="hibernateTemplate" />
 </bean><
 <bean name="inscripcionHabilitacionVehicFacade" class="com.reglamb.projvehimerc.service.HabilitacionVehicular_InscripcionFacadeImpl" />
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
 </beans>
```

What's the error ? thnks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you set `hibernate.connection.provider_class` to `org.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`.

It should be `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider` instead.

Comment: change it, gave me :Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]

Comment: Perhaps you don't have hibernate-c3p0 jar in the classpath.

Comment: NB that you need a matching version of hibernate-c3p0 jar to your hibernate core jar... http://betterlogic.com/roger/2013/08/hibernate-c3p0-woe/