# Hibernate: C3P0 properties ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I'm getting the following warning:

```
15:41:51,043 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
```

Here are the properties as set in my Hibernate.xfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
... (and other properties)
```

I don't have any other configuration about C3P0, aside the above properties.

Here are all my Hibernate and C3P0 dependencies configured in the Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

What I need to do in order to be able to read the properties that at the moment are ignored?

Answer (score 12):

From this [post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1014481&view=next) it appears you are missing the `hibernate-c3p0` dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to match the version with that used in `hibernate-core`

Comment: @user1883212 in that case see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277130/i-can-not-run-c3p0connectionprovider#16386038)

Comment: ok, I added the provider class as explained, but now I get: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider

Comment: That class is located in `hibernate-c3p0.jar` as provided by the above dependency. Ensure that this is on your classpath

Comment: it works if I use hibernate-c3p0 4.1.10.Final but not if I use 4.3.0.final. The class is not found in the second case.